# WARN No task registered for key TrackPlayer

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

I am using the `react-native-track-player (2.1.3)` to implement an audio player in a react-native application. When I initialize the track player in my project I get the following warning message.

> WARN  No task registered for key TrackPlayer

[image]

I followed one of the solutions found in a similar [closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/55), but it is opened a very long time ago. Anyhow it did not work, also.

**Following is the solution found in GitHub:** (Add the following code to index.js (the entry file of the app))

```
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({}).then(async () => {
})
```

If somebody is using react-native-track-player and solve this issue, can you please provide an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I am also using track player in my project.
my solution is add service in **index.js** file you can try this one

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() => require('./service.js'));
```

and I have created **service.js** file inside my root folder

```
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';


module.exports = async function () {

  try {
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play', () => {
      TrackPlayer.play()
    })

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause', () => {
      TrackPlayer.pause()
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-next', () => {
      TrackPlayer.skipToNext()
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-previous', () => {
      TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious()
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-stop', () => {
      TrackPlayer.destroy()
    });
  } catch (error) { }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I was following along with this tutorial from Youtube [Mobile App - Make Your Own Music Player](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPw5vCXhrmc&list=PLG2wK_RjmxlumV1_EAlz0LajHbvMO1ukh&index=4&t=3054s)
2. And this link from react native docs: [React Native Track Player](https://react-native-track-player.js.org/docs/basics/installation)
3. Then rather than importing the file into index.js, I just create a function inside index.js file. This is the documentations link: [Playback Service docs page](https://react-native-track-player.js.org/docs/basics/playback-service)

This was enough me. I hope that helps!

```
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

export const onRegisterPlayback = async() => {
    
     TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play', () => TrackPlayer.play());

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause', () => TrackPlayer.pause());

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-stop', () => TrackPlayer.destroy())
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() => onRegisterPlayback)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the Image. Add Service.js file in the Root Folder

[image]

And Copy and Paste the following code below.

```
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';


module.exports = async function () {

try {
TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play', () => {
  TrackPlayer.play()
})

TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause', () => {
  TrackPlayer.pause()
});

TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-next', () => {
  TrackPlayer.skipToNext()
});

TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-previous', () => 
{
  TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious()
});

TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-stop', () => {
  TrackPlayer.destroy()
});
 } catch (error) { }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the mistake was that I had put the bootstrap in **/src/index.ts**

**(WRONG)**

```
AppRegistry.registerRunnable(appName, async initialProps => {...})
TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() => tpService);
```

but this bootstrap needed to be in **/index.js**

**(RIGHT)**

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() => tpService);
```